# How to create a nav with: hover and .active

Tags: html, css

So I want in my navigation the current page to have a underline and color red.
The red box ix my current page, bad if I change page for example to: Work that needs to be red/underline. I tried to put in codepen.io bad never use it so that didnt work out.
[image: Example]

```
My code:

    HTML
    <div class="full-header">
          <div class="header">
              <div class="nav">
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
             <p class="header-text">May I introduce my self?</p>
             <hr class="line">
             <h2 class="header-text-small">front End Developer</h2>
             <div class="button">Aphryv</div>
        </div>

    CSS

    .full-header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background: url(img/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .header {
        width: 75%;
        height: 60px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /*background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);*/
    }

    .nav {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .nav ul {

    }

    .nav ul li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 20px 10px;
        line-height: 55px;
    }

    .nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .nav ul li a:hover {
        color: red;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. It probably helps to put this up on a site like codepen.io so you have a working (or rather, failing) example that you can easily share.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088986/highlight-current-link-with-css-or-js

Comment: @Paulie_D I hope I can fix my problem with just html/css (Haven't learn javascript yet)

Comment: If you only have a small site (few pages) this can be done with HTML/CSS  but if you have many pages then JS is your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large sites, Javascript is the optimal solution.

However, for small sites with only a few pages then an HTML/CSS solution exists.

If this is your menu

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then all that is necessary **on each page** is to assign a class of, say, "current" to the list item (or link) that applies to that page.

So for the "Work" page:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="current"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then your CSS would be.

```
li.current a {
color:red;
text-decoraton:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple class to the body tag of each page, for example:

```
<body class="navMain">
<body class="navWork">
<body class="navAboutme">
<body class="navContact">
```

Then add a further class to each link:

```
<li><a href="index.html" class="highMain">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="highWork">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="highAboutme">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="highContact">Contact</a></li>
```

Finally write some CSS that targets each link, only when the user is on that same page:

```
.navMain .highMain .nav ul li, .navWork .highWork .nav ul li, .navAboutme .highAboutme .nav ul li, .navContact .highContact .nav ul li {border: 1px solid red;}
```

I've over elaborated the CSS for you to understand.

Hope this helps